# How to automate version changes in pom.xml

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

During new release of product, I need to change versions in each pom.xml. From current-SNAPSHOT I need to change it to some new released version.I want to automate this because it takes lot of time during release.

`<groupId>com.abc.myProduct</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproduct</artifactId>
  <version>current-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>`

Any idea to avoid this manual work.I tried maven replacer plugin but no use.

Comment: You mean the version of your own project of the version of dependencies?

Comment: Both dependencies and project

Comment: "... I need to change versions in each pom.xml" - when you realize that you don't need this, life will become much easier :)

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev Could you explain what you mean by your comment?

Comment: POM versions don't matter for release cycle. It's the versions that are built - they matter. And those have timestamp, build number, commit hash, whatever - they are unique anyway. You can release binaries w/o ever changing POM version. Which simplifies scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Use `versions-maven-plugin`

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.0
```

you can see this link : [Changing the project version](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/set.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: If there is a number of projects you always release together, think about building a multi-module project. Then you can build and release (Maven release plugin) all modules together without the problem you describe above.

If you release your projects separately, you need build them in the right order (so that if A depends on B, you build B first). On each project you can use `versions:use-releases` to automatically replace all SNAPSHOT versions by their released counterparts (https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-releases-mojo.html). Then you use the Maven release plugin to build the project, so that you publish a release version to your repository. Iterate until you have built all projects.